# Laravel request validation error. Required error

Tags: laravel

Laravel validation error. " required " fail

URL : /deneme/xxxx-yyyy

Validation :

```
$request->validate([
    'slug' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'slug'],
]);
```

Route :

```
Route::prefix('deneme')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\WorkShopsController@workshop');
});
```

required fail ?

success :)
Route::get('/{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\WorkShopsController@list')->where('slug', '[a-zA-Z-0-9]+');;;

Comment: Route parameters are not request inputs

Comment: ? example please.

Comment: example of what ... route parameters are not inputs of the request ... the request does not have an input named `slug` as that is a route parameter, it is a separate thing ... and what is this `slug` validation rule you are trying to use?

Answer (score -2):

Change this:

> $request->validate([
> 'slug' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'slug'], ]);

To this. It has to be in the following format

> $this->validate($request, [ 'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|slug' ]);

Thats the proper format for Laravel validation. Make sure you have an an input with the name="slug" on the previous page

Comment: whats your error? Can you provide a little more information on what you are trying to do

Comment: @max234435 they don't have an input named `slug` ... `slug` is their route parameter

Comment: @lagbox there is a lot going on with this question, just trying to figure out what they are trying to do in the first place